# Compiler errors on setter and getter functions in QT

Tags: c++, qt

In the midst of making a test program I've come across a problem that has me boggled. I have googled and looked on here and haven't found an answer to the problem so thought I might just ask.

The issue: I get compiler errors on a getter and a setter function I made in QT. Basically I need to be able to set and get a QList object.

What am I overlooking? I think I might be doing something wrong with QList but I can't see what.

**SliderArray.h**

```
#ifndef SLIDERARRAY_H
#define SLIDERARRAY_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QList>
#include <QSlider>

class SliderArray : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SliderArray(int sliders, QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~SliderArray();

    //getter function for slider data
    QList<int> GetSliderData();

    //setter function for slider data
    void SetSliderData(QList<int>);

private:
    QList<int> integerList1; //Qlist Object to hold data
```

**SliderArray.cpp**

```
SliderArray::GetSliderData()
{
    return integerList1;
}

SliderArray::SetSliderData(QList<int> datalist)
{
    integerList1 = datalist;
}
```

these are the errors I get when I try to compile:

```
...\sliderarray.cpp:24: error: prototype for 'intSliderArray::GetSliderData()' does not match any in class 'SliderArray'
 SliderArray::GetSliderData()
 ^
...\sliderarray.h:16: error: candidate is: QList<int> SliderArray::GetSliderData()
     QList<int> GetSliderData();
            ^
...\sliderarray.cpp:29: error: prototype for 'int SliderArray::SetSliderData(QList<int>)' does not match any in class  'SliderArray'
 SliderArray::SetSliderData(QList<int> datalist)
 ^

...\sliderarray.h:19: error: candidate is: void SliderArray::SetSliderData(QList<int>)
     void SetSliderData(QList<int>);
          ^
```

Comment: You missed to specify the return type in the function definitions.

Comment: It's exactly that; you're missing the data types at the beginning of the function definitions.

Comment: "It's exactly that; you're missing the data types at the beginning of the function definitions."  Ofcourse! *facepalm* Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cpp file you should have:

```
QList<int> SliderArray::GetSliderData()
{
    return integerList1;
}

void SliderArray::SetSliderData(QList<int> datalist)
{
    integerList1 = datalist;
}
```

This has nothing to do with Qt, you're just missing the return types.